# Did church fathers express a view of Elihu?

Tags: church-fathers, job

Elihu is a figure in Job, and he can have quite a lot of interpretations, radically different ones as seen on this answer on [Bible Hermeneutics](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/164/interpretations-of-elihu-in-job?rq=1). Is he a repetitive arrogant youth or a prefiguration of Elijah?

Did any church fathers express an opinion on Elihu? If so, where and what was it?

Comment: The answers in SE-BH cover the two main arguments. (I favour the 'Elijah' argument, Elihu being a 'precursor' to the words of the Lord in the whirlwind.) Up-voted +1 as it will be interesting to know of the early fathers' comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gregory the Great (known by the Roman church as one of the great eight doctors) portrays [Elihu](http://www.lectionarycentral.com/GregoryMoralia/Book23.html) as a prototype of vainglorious young men in the Church.

For example,

> 12. All these words, which are uttered by him through swelling pride, must be rather glanced at by the way than expounded more attentively. For whatsoever is deficient in solid gravity, needs not any elaborate exposition. But I think I need only suggest in a few words, that Eliu was more wise, as long as he remained silent on account of his age, but that in despising a multitude of years in others, and setting himself above them, he shewed plainly his childish folly. For both greater age speaks, against his opinion, and wisdom is taught by multitude of years. Because, though length of life does not confer intelligence, yet it gives it much exercise by constant practice.